# How can I use passwords with bash special characters on the command line?

Tags: bash, password, special-characters, history-expansion

I have a command line that takes a password . The password starts with characters '!1'. E.g. '!1x9y377s' . If I execute a command with that password, then history expansion occurs and the first two letters '!1' are replaced with the 1st history entry.
E.g.

```
ll
...list entries
echo !1x9y377s
llx9y377s
```

but what I wanted was:

```
ll
...list entries
echo !1x9y377s
!1x9y377s
```

## Research

I soon realized that this was history expansion occurring prior to bash parsing.
I searched for: How can I stop history expansion from occurring on passwords passed in the command line?
Which resulted in things like this :

1. [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters)
2. [stackover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782202/get-and-use-a-password-with-special-characters-in-bash-shell)
3. [berkley tcsh docs](https://nature.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/History_substitution.html)
   It states: "The `!' may be preceded by a `\' to prevent its special meaning"

## I tried executing:

```
ll
...list entries
echo '!1x9y377s'
!1x9y377s
```

and

```
ll
...list entries
echo \!1x9y377s
!1x9y377s
```

both of which worked.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You can also turn off history expansion: `set +H` -- turn it back on with `set -H`

Answer (score 3):

Their are two ways to approach this. According to [the berkley docs](https://nature.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/History_substitution.html):
"The `!` may be preceded by a `\` to prevent its special meaning"

But, if you don't want to go escaping, use a single quote around the password. E.g.

```
ll
...list entries
echo '!1x9y377s'
!1x9y377s
```

According to the Bash Manual:
[3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (') preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.